# how to import local packages?

Tags: go, intellij-idea

My GOPATH and GOROOT

```
GOPATH="/Users/road/IdeaProjects/MiniJVM"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

My golang project structure

```
Myproject
---.idea
---src
   ---cmd
      ---cmd.go
   ---test
      ---test.go
```

test.go file, I will use the imports from other packages .What is wrong with my code? Or the import path has some problem?

```
package main

import (
     "fmt"
     "cmd"
)
func main()  {
     command := &Cmd{}//unresolved type 'Cmd'
}
```

cmd.go file

```
package cmd

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

/*
    jaca [-option] class [args...]
*/
type Cmd struct {
    HelpFlag bool
    VersionFlag bool
    CpOption string
    Class string
    Args []string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change the folder name "cmd" to other name,because there is already an package "cmd" in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Use the full path:

```
import (
    "github.com/myname/myproject/src/cmd"
)
```